# How to read data from Firebase ONCE using java/android?

Tags: java, android, events, listener, firebase

I'm trying to use the Java API to read data from a Firebase database in an Android application in the onCreate() event. In other words, I'm trying to do the simplest read possible, the equivalent of ...

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {

});
```

...in the Javascript API. I'm trying to use the addEventListenerForSingleValueEvent() method, but it seems to want me to override the onDataChange() method, which is not what I want.  I want to get the data out when the program execution reaches this line, regardless of database events. Here's my (unfinished) function....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.poll_table);    

        // First get the table layout
        tbl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.pollsTable);

        // Now let's create the header
        TableRow tHead = createPollsTableHeader();

        // Add header to tableLayout
        tbl.addView(tHead, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // Add all polls in ref as rows
        polls.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            // DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE

        }
    }
```

I don't even think this is the correct method. I just want to be able to get a Datasnapshot that I can iterate through and get data out of, like...

```
for (Datasnapshot child : datasnapshot) {
}
```

..just as if I were using the `ref.once('value', function(snapshot)` event in the Javaxcript API.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That is the right method, and you're on the right track.  The naming is just a little confusing (sorry!).  If you do the addListenerForSingleValueEvent, your overridden onDataChange method will be called exactly once, with a DataSnapshot, just as you wish (and just like "ref.once('value' ...)" would do).

So you should be able to do:

```
// Add all polls in ref as rows
polls.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use snapshot.getChildren() ```for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {```

Comment: @realgt Oops, you're right.  Updated the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer can you please update the answer with fetching the data from it ?

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer So if you have two related queries, for example get an id from a location and query another collection to get the data, then I will have to write two listeners wired through onDataChange?

Comment: Hi, I have something similar and it's working so far, I get the data only once but if I make changes on the data (adding a new element for example) when I close the app and open it again I don't get the updated data. I do have Internet connection and I do have the setPersistenceEnabled set to true so it works offline as well. Any ideas why I don't get the information from the backend if there is connection?

Comment: Just found the solution to my question: keepSynced(false); that will do the job

Comment: In polls.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()  where do you get the polls. part from, and what do you put if I have different names in my project?