# Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent does not read data once in android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using firebase in android.
I want to read the data in firebase for one time.

I read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904613/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-once-using-java-android) , It says `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will read the data once.

So I used `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` function, but it repeatedly reads the data from `firebase`.

How can I read data only once from the `firebase`? thanks in advance.

```
            final Firebase checkBuy = new Firebase(URI);

            checkBuy.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    checkPurchase(snapshot);

                    addListView();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: so you tried the answer for the question you linked and it didn't work? show us your code.

Comment: I updated question. addListView and checkPurchase function repeatedly called

Comment: I was stupid, I declared addListenerForSingleValueEvent in fragment activity. So everytime fragment created, addListenerForSingleValueEvent function called again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its cause was not firebase, fragment.

I used addListenerForSingleValueEvent in viewPager's fragment. 
When viewPager's fragment called, viewPager destroy fragment and create fragment again.

To prevent fragment destroy, you need to override this.

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    Log.d(TAG, "don't destroy!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a database reference object, the same way one can add an event listener, it can also be removed, using `removeEventListener`.

Instead of creating an anonymous object like this

```
    checkBuy.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    checkPurchase(snapshot);

                    addListView();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
    });
```

you can create a named object of `ValueEventListener` and remove it from the database reference object using `removeEventListener`, at the end of the `onDataChange` method

```
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    checkPurchase(snapshot);

                    addListView();

                    checkBuy.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
    });

    checkBuy.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

The code inside `onDataChange` method gets executed only once as the `ValueEventListener` object is removed as soon as the last line of the method gets executed.