# Firebase android how to prevent FirebaseRecyclerAdapter automatically updating?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` which I do not want to keep updating the `RecyclerView`. This is because I have it so it populates the view with items based on how many 'views' they have in the database. The problem is, if other people view the items, the list you see in the app will keep changing order.
Is there a way to stop the recycler adapter from constantly listening for data changes or will I have to go about this another way?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is not listening for the data changes an option?

Comment: @TylerPfaff what do you mean? As far as I can tell there is no way to disable listening for data changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adapters in FirebaseUI are live-bound to the data at the Query/DatabaseReference that you construct them with. There is no way to turn this behavior off in the adapter.

But you can easily create a `ValueEventListener` that populates a static `List<T>` and feeds that into an `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: How do I use `ValueEventListener` to get multiple children from an item in the database? I have `MYURL.firebaseio.com/items`. In items, there are several children that all contain multiple children themselves, how do I access each child individually to add to a list?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904613/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-once-using-java-android

Comment: Thanks! I got it working and managed to use a swipe refresh to refresh it when I need. Thanks for the help.