# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter : Show sorted data only once after downloaded from database, prevent sorting at runtime

Tags: android, firebase

I had referred the fragment below in [Firebase/quickstart-android/database](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/fragment/MyTopPostsFragment.java) as reference.

```
public class MyTopPostsFragment extends PostListFragment {

public MyTopPostsFragment() {}

@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    // [START my_top_posts_query]
    // My top posts by number of stars
    String myUserId = getUid();
    Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(myUserId)
            .orderByChild("starCount");
    // [END my_top_posts_query]

    return myTopPostsQuery;
    }
}
```

I want to read data from `Firebase` Database then sort the data by `starCount` when users launched the app just like what shown in the quickstart example. 
This has been achieved via the example.

---

Now the issue,

I does not want it to automatically sort the data when users increased `starCount` while using the app. It causes the data move up / down when users clicked the `star` button. I just want to update `starCount` in Firebase database.

But Using the above code, Whenever user marks any post Starred, That moves up/down according into the list based on `starCount` automatically.

---

What I have tried so far,

I tried adding `childEventListener`, `listnerForSingleValueEvent` and `valueEventListener` but I do not know what code to be added for `onDataChange`, `onCancelled`, `onChildAdded`, `onChildChanged` and others.

I referred other questions like
[Firebase android how to prevent FirebaseRecyclerAdapter automatically updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465409/firebase-android-how-to-prevent-firebaserecycleradapter-automatically-updating?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but still I not sure what to do to prevent list getting changed automatically by marking star to the post.

Hope that anyone can help me for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue :** When marking star to a post it moves ahead in list, and high ranked post goes on top.

**Reason :** The code of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

```
public FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(Class<T> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<VH> viewHolderClass, Query ref) {
        this.mModelClass = modelClass;
        this.mModelLayout = modelLayout;
        this.mViewHolderClass = viewHolderClass;
        this.mSnapshots = new FirebaseArray(ref);
        this.mSnapshots.setOnChangedListener(new OnChangedListener() {
            public void onChanged(EventType type, int index, int oldIndex) {
                switch(null.$SwitchMap$com$firebase$ui$database$FirebaseArray$OnChangedListener$EventType[type.ordinal()]) {
                case 1:
                    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.this.notifyItemInserted(index);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(index);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.this.notifyItemRemoved(index);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.this.notifyItemMoved(oldIndex, index);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Incomplete case statement");
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Here you can see that whenever any item of the adapter is changed, it gets notified and the list gets rearranged by the order you provided in the query.

**Existing code :** `MyTopPostFragment` in this you are generating a query which will always used to show the list, remember this query will be used while the adapter is notified as well as I told above.

```
public class MyTopPostsFragment extends PostListFragment {

    public MyTopPostsFragment() {}

    @Override
    public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        String myUserId = getUid();
        Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(myUserId)
                .orderByChild("starCount");

        return myTopPostsQuery;
    }
}
```

---

**Solution :**

MyTopPostFragment - Change (Remove Order from Query)

```
@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    String myUserId = getUid();
    Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(myUserId);
    //   .orderByChild("starCount"); Removed order from here

    return myTopPostsQuery;
}
```

PostListFragment - Change (Add Order To Query)

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up Layout Manager, reverse layout
        mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        // Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query
        Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);
        postsQuery.orderByChild("starCount"); // Added Order HERE
        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class, R.layout.item_post,
                PostViewHolder.class, postsQuery) {
```