# OnDataChange Firebase Android Listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I' am trying to retrieve data from firebase database, this method is called when you enter to the app and never listens OnDataChange. If I upload a new image to firebase, OnDataChange is called and shows the last url I have introduced. I want to retrieve all data urls but I thought this method is always called no matter is new data on the realtime database. Thank you in advice.

```
    private void prepareAlbums() {

    // storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Images").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().toString());

    System.out.print("user "+ firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    databaseReference.getRoot().child("user-images")
        .child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (td != null) {
              Iterator iterator = td.entrySet().iterator();
              while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                String url = (String) entry.getValue();
                System.out.print("url "+ url);
                urlArray.add(url);
              }
            }
          }

          @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
        });

    CardImage a;
    for (String s : urlArray) {
      a = new CardImage("usuario1", 3, s, "madrid");
      albumList.adenter code hered(a);
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

This is my Database Structure

```
spear-e5a6a
  user-images
   3cAhNM75JdaeojrJ5RSjpBhonu63  // userid
   -KjN5Jr31u5lPwubAwEF: 
     "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/spe..."
   -KjN5Nv0Sk8sC6dqDgrq: 
     "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/spe..."
```

I solved the problem like this

```
databaseReference.getRoot().child("images")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        imageArray.clear();
                        cardList.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot imageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + imageSnapshot.getKey());
                            ImageInfo image = imageSnapshot.getValue(ImageInfo.class);
                            imageArray.add(image);

                        }
                        render(imageArray);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }

                });


 private void render(ArrayList<ImageInfo> imgInfo) {
        final ArrayList<UserInfo> userArray = new ArrayList<>();


        CardImage card;
        for (ImageInfo imageInfo : imgInfo) {
            card = new CardImage(imageInfo.getName(), imageInfo.getRating(), imageInfo.getUrl(), imageInfo.getProvince(), imageInfo.getTimeStamp());
            cardList.add(card);
        }


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

images
  1494101684644:  //timestamp
  1494101402668
    comentary: 
    name: 
    province: 
    rating: 
    timeStamp: 
    url: 
    usermail: 
    voted: 
users
   //user id YMlB6t3Yp1Rs2mcpc9MstUSVD5z2:
   email: 
   images
   1494101402668:  timestamp
   1494101684644: 
   name:
```

I don't really know if its the proper way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data from Firebase ONCE using java/android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904613/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-once-using-java-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the declaration of your `urlArray` in your `onDataChange()` method. Otherwise is null because this method is executed asynchronously.

For other approach, please visit this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576441/querying-data-from-firebase) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723139/wait-firebase-async-retrive-data-in-android).

Hope it helps.